# removing [u''] in the django template

Tags: python, html, json, django, django-templates

I'm trying to load JSON into a Django template, and this goes well. But I get [] around it and 'u before it. I was wondering if there is something I could do against it. this is the code I use:

```
json_response = requests.get(endpoint + "appointments?user="+user+"&access_token="+token+"&start="+str(int(timestamp_start))+"&end="+str(int(timestamp_end))+"&valid=true").json()
appointmentsVrijdag = json_response['response']['data']
return render(request, template, {"appointmentsVrijdag": appointmentsVrijdag})
```

Then, to load it in the template I use the following code:

```
            {% for appointment in appointmentsVrijdag %}
            {% if appointment.cancelled != True %}
                <tr>
                     <td>
                         {{ appointment.teachers }}
                         {{ appointment.subjects }}
                     </td>
                </tr>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

I was hoping to get some help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `appointment.teachers` or `appointment.subjects` are lists, you may just join the items inside in the template using the [built-in `join` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#join):

```
{{ appointment.teachers|join:", " }}
{{ appointment.subjects|join:", " }}
```